# SAML error : A node is used in a different document than the one that created it

Tags: java, xml, saml, docx4j, xerces

I have three war files running on same JBoss server. These are configured with spring saml. I am facing the below error when ever the metadata refresh cycle happens from ADFS(Identity provider).

```
http-0.0.0.0-8443-10) Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception: org.w3c.dom.DOMException: WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: A node is used in a different document than the one that created it.
    at org.apache.xerces.dom.ParentNode.internalInsertBefore(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.dom.ParentNode.insertBefore(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.dom.NodeImpl.appendChild(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.parseInputStream(Decrypter.java:821) [:20021210]
    at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptDataToDOM(Decrypter.java:599) [:20021210]
    at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptUsingResolvedEncryptedKey(Decrypter.java:784) [:20021210]
    at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptDataToDOM(Decrypter.java:524) [:20021210]
    at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptDataToList(Decrypter.java:442) [:20021210]
    at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptData(Decrypter.java:403) [:20021210]
    at org.opensaml.saml2.encryption.Decrypter.decryptData(Decrypter.java:141) [:]
    at org.opensaml.saml2.encryption.Decrypter.decrypt(Decrypter.java:69) [:]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:199) [:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:87) [:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:87) [:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [:4.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [:4.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87) [:1.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344) [:4.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261) [:4.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285) [:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261) [:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [:1.8.0_45]
```

**Note:** one out of the three war files is using docx4j library to generate word documents. I suspect the same library is culprit as it uses xml parser's internally.

experts help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link [SpringSecurity-SAML(OpenSAML): Failed to unmarshall assertion: getting org.w3c.dom.DOMException: WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31060849/springsecurity-samlopensaml-failed-to-unmarshall-assertion-getting-org-w3c-d) helped me in finding the root cause: "Multiple implementations of xerces in the project" 
I had suppressed docx4j to use existing instance of JDK xerces implementation rather than creating new instance of xerces implementation ships along with docx4j library. 
Add the below property to docx4j.properties file in class path

docx4j.javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.donotset=true

Answer (score 0):

Try importNode to add a node created in one Document to another: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#importNode(org.w3c.dom.Node,%20boolean)